# How can I send a jquery var to php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I try to send a var with jquery, ajax php doesn't receive it, and I don't know why.

This is my script:

```
function showHiddenUserInfoPanel(id){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#admin-resume').fadeToggle('slow', 'linear', function(){
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            data: "userid="+id, // Also I tried with : data: {userid: id},
            url: "user-profile.php",
            success: function(){
                $('#info-user').fadeToggle('slow', 'linear');
                alert(id); // I receive the correct id value
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is my user-profile.php:

```
<div id="activity_stats">
    <h3>Viendo el perfil de <?php echo $_POST["userid"]; ?></h3>
</div>
```

Can anybody can help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: Use Fiddler to track the HTTP requests and check if the are correct...

Comment: Why are you using `$(document).ready()` inside of a function?  You want to wait until the document is ready before you _call_ the function, but within the function itself it might not do what you expect.  It means you're not actually _doing_ something in that function, you're just binding to an event.

Comment: @David Well, if the DOM is already ready, the function will be called immediately.

Comment: @ZombieHunter In my firebug appear: userid 11, in console tab 
David I think like lonesomeday.

Comment: @jask: If FireBug is showing that the value is being posted, then PHP is receiving it.  What are you actually doing with the value after that?  In response to the AJAX call, you're just fading in a `div` on the current page.  Does that fade-in work?  You're not really _doing_ anything with the AJAX response.  So I guess the question is... What indication do you have that something is wrong?  Because based on your description so far, this code is doing exactly what it looks like it's doing.

Comment: @David At the moment, I want to print the id value, the next step is do a function call to show user information, but firstly, I want to do in a little steps for see that all works correctly. This is the wrong: "Notice: Undefined index: userid in /var/www/Proyecto-FP2/user-profile.php on line 4 " and the fade-in works perfectly

Comment: `async: true` is the default, you don't need to include that in your options.

Comment: You said that "php doesn't receive it". How do you know that? Did you open the "user-profile.php" in a seperate window or tab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it just me or you are not using the response at all?

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(){
    $('#info-user').fadeToggle('slow', 'linear');
  }
});
```

Your anonymous `success` function is ignoring all responses. I suspect your `#info-user` should be an empty element and you are not getting a visual feedback.

An example could be:

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(response){
    $('#info-user').html(response).fadeToggle('slow', 'linear');
  }
});
```

Other alternative could be using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Just to add more information, the jQuery `.load()` function may also be useful for his needs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @Alexander For load() is the same as ajax() but only with data, url and callback? Thanks :)

Comment: @jask, url, data and callback in that order ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help :), but I don't need a response, really ?

Comment: If you don't use the response then you won't get `user-profile.php`'s contents (after sending the request with the `userid` parameter.)